# Does html get returned as data in an ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, echo

is html in the file of a requested ajax url  returned as data?  For example:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'someunknownurl.com/testing.php',
       success: function(data){ alert(data);
                       }
       });
```

And lets say the php in 'someunknownurl.com/testing.php' has this:

```
<h1>testing</h1>
```

Will the html be sent back to the ajax request as data?

Comment: have you tried to run what you have there?

Comment: actually i just did and the html is "echoed" back to the ajax request or is considered data basically.

Answer (score 2):

If `someunknownurl.com` is not under the same domain as your HTML/JavaScript page, you won't get result because there is a 'crossdomain' limitation.

There is one way to do cross domain AJAX: use JSONP (the remote URL must support JSONP).

If the AJAX request succeeded, the format of `data` may depend on may conditions.

1. the `Content-Type` in response header.
2. the `dataType` you set in the AJAX options.

You had better read the `$.ajax` jQuery document: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: have you read my answer carefully?

Comment: there was never the question of "cross-domain" issue in my question...not sure where your getting that.

Comment: because your request may fail, and you may get nothing.

Comment: if the request succeeds, it depends on the response of 'testing.php', you may get an object, and you may get a string of html. it depends. please refer to the jQuery document, you will find that I am right  :D

Comment: @shawn: I agree with your commentary about helping people to become better programmers, but disagree that Stack Overflow is entirely counter-productive in this area. True, there are a number of users who will help even the most egregious help vampires, but questions can also be downvoted and/or closed, which to my knowledge barely happens elsewhere on the web. So, it's a mixed bag - and a hard problem to solve!

Comment: (Whilst I would say this kind of commentary is mostly fine in the comments, it is not on-topic for answers, which need to be focussed on the technical matter at hand).